# Discord Rank Command

Tags: python, discord.py, system, rank

I tried a few times to get the rank(if he is the user with the most xp, or 2th most ad so on) of the player to the rankcard, but I only come to the point that I list the experience from the most to the lowest.
Can somebody help me how I can get the rank of the player?

```
    @commands.command(aliases = ["rank","lvl"])
    async def level(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        async with ctx.typing():
            user = ctx.message.author
            with open("level.json","r") as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["level"]
            exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["experience"]


            rankcard = Image.open("Zumtest.png")

            url = requests.get(user.avatar_url)
            avatar = Image.open(BytesIO(url.content))
            avatar = avatar.resize((177, 177));
            avatar.convert('RGBA')
            bigsize = (avatar.size[0] * 3, avatar.size[1] * 3)
            mask = Image.new("L", bigsize, 0)
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
            draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
            mask = mask.resize(avatar.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            avatar.putalpha(mask)

            rankcard.paste(avatar, (100,40), avatar)

            lvltext = "Level {}".format(lvl)
            exptext = f"{exp} XP"


            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(rankcard)
            font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)

            draw.text((255,60), lvltext, (0, 0, 0,), font=font)


            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(rankcard)

            draw.text((255,117), exptext, (0, 0, 0,), font=font)



        rankcard.save("profile.png")

        await ctx.send(file = discord.File("profile.png"))
```

That is the level.json

```
{"719479402953572383": {"504641949068689430": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can simply use `sorted` to get the ordering, and then `enumerate` to number them:

```py
users = users[ctx.guild.id] 

ranking = {key: rank for rank, key in enumerate(sorted(users, key=users.get, reverse=True), 1)}

user_rank = ranking[member.id]
```

This does not take into account for ties. You could use this instead to have tied scores. If you wanted all the tied keys to have the same rank. We have:

```py
r = {key: rank for rank, key in enumerate(sorted(set(users.values()), reverse=True), 1)}
ranking = {k: r[v] for k,v in users.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            users = users[str(ctx.guild.id)]

            r = {key: rank for rank, key in enumerate(sorted(set(users.values()), reverse=True), 1)}
            ranking = {k: r[v] for k,v in users.items()}


            user_rank = ranking[member.id]
```

I changed the code a little bit

```
Ignoring exception in command level:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lasse\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lasse\Documents\Discord Bots\MyBot\cogs\LevelSystem.py", line 63, in level
    r = {key: rank for rank, key in enumerate(sorted(set(users.values()), reverse=True), 1)}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

But know I dont know how to fix this Error